# Insert dash after every 4th character in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want insert a dash after every 4th character in input. I have a credit card input box. When a user is typing and reaches each 4th character, then jQuery will insert a hyphen (`-`).

For example: `1234-5678-1234-1231`

**UPDATE:** I'm trying some codes and i think i'm so close to correct code but i have some problems. Here is my code sample;

```
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {

var cardValue = $('.creditCardText').val(),
    cardLength = cardValue.length;

if ( cardLength < 5 ) {
    if ( cardLength % 4 == 0 ) {
        console.log('4 lük geldi');
        cardValue += "-";
        $('.creditCardText').val(cardValue);
    }
} else {
    if ( cardLength % 5 == 0 ) {
        console.log('5 lük geldi');
        cardValue += "-";
        $('.creditCardText').val(cardValue);

    }
}

});
```

Comment: Use four different input fields and combine them server-side. Doing it client-side is not worth the trouble and can confuse your users when they're not expecting it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have code?

Comment: @Blazemonger, I'm not a UX guy, but the sites that pull this off with placeholders certainly don't bother me.  It is possible to do without irritating your users, I think.

Comment: Or use a single input, and strip out dashes / insert them server side.

Comment: Not all Credit Cards are 4-4-4-4......

Comment: @Brad the usual approach is to add the dashes AFTER the user leaves the field (`.on('blur', ...)`), not while the user is still typing. This is better for a number of reasons.

Comment: @Blazemonger, Can you elaborate?  I'd like to learn the problem with having those dashes there already in place while the user types.  (I'm referring to the sites where there is one text box with blanks in places of numbers, with dashes in place.  I understand the confusion that occurs when unexpected things appear later.)

Comment: @Blazemonger it was previously, but now have changed. Because some credit card have different character size. Some has 16, some has 24 character.

Comment: @AtesGoral 

`$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {

 

 if ( $(this).val().length == 4 || $(this).val().length == 8 ) {
  $(this).val().join(', ');
 }

 
})`

Comment: @Brad The problems come when the user tries to delete the dashes, and can't; or when he tries to add his own dashes or spaces, and the programmer wasn't expecting it. Generally, it "feels rude" to edit someone's text while they're still typing it. If you're going to re-write my text entry, wait until I've had a chance to rewrite it myself.

Comment: It's usually disorienting for users when their raw input is tampered with. Allow the users to enter the numbers either with dashes, spaces or nothing at all (remember that they could be copy/pasting an already typed in number that could be in some other form). Do your normalization transparently and process the data in the form you like.

Answer (score 29):

I absolutely love this plugin for automatic formatting:
[here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

So long as you're already using JQuery, that is.

You could easily force the dashes in with a single line of code, like follows:

```
$("#credit").mask("9999-9999-9999-9999");
```

When the user types in the field, the dashes will automatically appear in the right spot, and they will not be able to delete them.

In addition, you can accommodate for different lengths or formats of credit cards with the `?` character in your mask. For example, to accept inputs of 14 and 16 digits, you would do the following:

```
$("#credit").mask("9999-9999-9999-99?99");
```

Do keep in mind that this is only a client side validation

---

***Edit***: The mask plugin assumes that there is one, or finitely many, correct formats for the field. For example, there are only a few formats that credit card numbers come in. The plugin is there to ensure that your input will *only* be in one of those formats.

So technically, if you want a dash after every four digits, but for *any* number of digits, then this plugin is not right for you.

I would suggest you restrict the possible inputs to be reasonable, as there is certainly no such thing as a 1000-digit long credit card.  But if you really want that functionality, you'll have to write the script yourself or find another plugin. As of this time I'm not aware of one.

Comment: Someone mentioned that not all credit cards are the same format. You can also specify optional characters too, so to accomodate 4-4-4-2 you could write
`$("#credit").mask("9999-9999-9999-99?99");`

Comment: I was tried that but not enough for me. Because not all credit cards are the same format. Input area has 24 character and someone just put 18 character and it is enough for them. But someone have to 24 character. Is that a problem for this plugin?

Comment: @mrchad I'm not sure I understand, but you can specify that the input must be of different lengths, yes. Can you give an example? Maybe update your question with the different rules you want to be in place? If you show me what you want it to allow and not allow, I can help you write the mask

Comment: I just want when a user is typing and reaches each 4th character, then jQuery will insert a hyphen. That's it no more, no less.

Comment: @mrchad I understand now. I'll update my answer to accommodate.

Comment: Thanks!. When i'm setting a value to the text box, the mask not applied.. Any Suggestion plz? And when i click inside the text box the value is gone..

Answer (score 21):

I've fixed up your code, but still strongly suggest server validation **and** using four text boxes, and smartly switching between them:

```js
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="creditCardText" />
```

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juspC/126/)

Comment: I upvoted because this is a quick solution, but you need an 'if' statement before calling .join("-") in the third line. If you don't, when you only have one character left in the input field and you delete it, your code calls .match which returns null and then you immediately call .join on that null value, which results in a javascript error. Please update your answer. Other than that, this is a working solution.

Comment: @Mike.MKrallaProductions Thanks. Is the edit I just made what you mean?

Comment: @think123, I tried your code to add dashes after every 4 digit in credit card but it fails if user want to delete specific digit like 3rd or 2nd. And  also digit is not entered at a specific place like i want to add digit at 7th place it always append from last.

Comment: @Megha Yes, that's true. I personally would also recommend Nick's answer above, but in the case of the plugin not being able to be used, this would be a dirty, bad, but still reasonably usable solution.

Comment: You can improve it a little bit by only setting the value if there was a change. This will make arrows, Shift-Home and stuff like that work. Add as first line in the function:
`var curr = $jq(this).val();`.
Replace the last line in the function with:
`if (curr != foo) $jq(this).val(foo);`

Comment: My text is 89050342 . i want to make it like 89-05-0342 . Can you please suggest some regex for it ?

Comment: @vivek sure! use this: `mytext.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");`

Comment: @vivek I also found you a link that *may* be able to help you more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981487/insert-hyphens-in-javascript

Comment: @think123 i want to do the same in the keyup function as in your answer . i modified the regex like foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join("-"); but it inserting after every 2 characters . My text is 89050342 . i want to make it like 89-05-0342 on keyup function . i mean autodash inserter . Please help .

Comment: @vivek yeah, I'm pretty sure you can just use the code I highlighted in my answer, and replace line 4 with like `foo = foo.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");` - pretty sure it will work for you ;)

Comment: @Yvette Glad I could help!

Comment: Ctrl+A / Ctrl+Home / Ctrl+End and the Mac variants do not work. This code will automatically deselect your select all

Comment: thanks @think123 you should implement this into your code above if you wanted to make this answer more foolproof :D

Comment: @zanderwar I'll have a look later. Just tested it and found a few logic bugs in the link, you may want to do the same. I'll fix it up and update the answer in due time :)

Answer (score 18):

#### Based on @think123 answer, in vanilla JS, without JQuery:

```js
document.querySelector('.creditCardText').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var foo = this.value.split("-").join("");
  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
  }
  this.value = foo;
});
```

```html
<input class="creditCardText" type="text">
```

*I know the question is about JQuery but I think this answer could help too.*

Comment: This helped me with a React project where I'm trying to stay away from jQuery. I'm using this since I'm trying to stay away from masked input components in npm. For my case, I don't need those since I'm dynamically tracking two types of strings on one input.

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a pure Javascript solution, look at my function below. It supports the American Express format (15 digits) as well as Visa, MasterCard and others (16 digits).

Watch out for the simple solutions that will replace the whole value and always put the focus at the end of the input: it can be annoying if the user edits what he previously entered.

```js
input_credit_card = function(input) {
  var format_and_pos = function(char, backspace) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;
    var pos = 0;
    var separator = " ";
    var value = input.value;

    if (char !== false) {
      start = input.selectionStart;
      end = input.selectionEnd;

      if (backspace && start > 0) // handle backspace onkeydown
      {
        start--;

        if (value[start] == separator) {
          start--;
        }
      }
      // To be able to replace the selection if there is one
      value = value.substring(0, start) + char + value.substring(end);

      pos = start + char.length; // caret position
    }

    var d = 0; // digit count
    var dd = 0; // total
    var gi = 0; // group index
    var newV = "";
    var groups = /^\D*3[47]/.test(value) ? // check for American Express
      [4, 6, 5] : [4, 4, 4, 4];

    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      if (/\D/.test(value[i])) {
        if (start > i) {
          pos--;
        }
      } else {
        if (d === groups[gi]) {
          newV += separator;
          d = 0;
          gi++;

          if (start >= i) {
            pos++;
          }
        }
        newV += value[i];
        d++;
        dd++;
      }
      if (d === groups[gi] && groups.length === gi + 1) // max length
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    input.value = newV;

    if (char !== false) {
      input.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    }
  };

  input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;

    // Check for tab and arrow keys (needed in Firefox)
    if (code !== 9 && (code < 37 || code > 40) &&
      // and CTRL+C / CTRL+V
      !(e.ctrlKey && (code === 99 || code === 118))) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var char = String.fromCharCode(code);

      // if the character is non-digit
      // OR
      // if the value already contains 15/16 digits and there is no selection
      // -> return false (the character is not inserted)

      if (/\D/.test(char) || (this.selectionStart === this.selectionEnd &&
          this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').length >=
          (/^\D*3[47]/.test(this.value) ? 15 : 16))) // 15 digits if Amex
      {
        return false;
      }
      format_and_pos(char);
    }
  });

  // backspace doesn't fire the keypress event
  input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) // backspace or delete
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      format_and_pos('', this.selectionStart === this.selectionEnd);
    }
  });

  input.addEventListener('paste', function() {
    // A timeout is needed to get the new value pasted
    setTimeout(function() {
      format_and_pos('');
    }, 50);
  });

  input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    // reformat onblur just in case (optional)
    format_and_pos(this, false);
  });
};

input_credit_card(document.getElementById('credit-card'));
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Payment</legend>
    <div>
      <label for="credit-card">Credit card</label>
      <input id="credit-card" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/217u7fru/)

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

By modifying the suggestion of ***@think123*** and ***@TheStoryCoder***,
I added selectionStart and SelectionEnd for cursor. After that increase cursor position at suitable place and modify the cursor position. It should solve the cursor position is at not as expected position.

```js
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {

  var ss, se, obj;
  obj = $(this);
  ss = obj[0].selectionStart;
  se = obj[0].selectionEnd;

  var curr = obj.val();

  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
  }

  if (((curr.length % 5 == 0) && ss == se && ss == curr.length) || (ss == se && (ss % 5 == 0))) {
    ss += 1;
    se += 1;
  }

  if (curr != foo) {
    $(this).val(foo);
    obj[0].selectionStart = ss;
    obj[0].selectionEnd = se;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="creditCardText" type="text">
```

Comment: I think this is more accurate one, it will support the edit value in between.

Answer (score 2):

Most easiest way is the following using simple javascript onkey and function... it will put a dash hyphen after every 3 characters you input/type.

```js
function addDash(element) {
  let ele = document.getElementById(element.id);
  ele = ele.value.split('-').join(''); // Remove dash (-) if mistakenly entered.

  let finalVal = ele.match(/.{1,3}/g).join('-');
  document.getElementById(element.id).value = finalVal;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="sector" id="sector" onkeyup="addDash(this)" required>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and use lowercase instead of UPPERCASE to write sentences. Thank you.

Comment: @EricAya 
Edited the answer but why is it important?

Comment: Because writing whole sentences in uppercase is considered rude. It's like shouting at someone.

Answer (score 1):

All others who have answered above me are right and their code is definitely short and neat, but is a bit advance, in the sense that they are either using regular expressions or a plugin. Something like this can also be achieved with basic js/jquery, which, judging from your sample code you are trying to achieve. As this question is around 3 years old, you must've gotten what you had wanted by now, but yes, you were close.. This is what you should have tried:

```js
$('.creditCardText').keyup(function() {
  var cctlength = $(this).val().length; // get character length

  switch (cctlength) {
    case 4:
      var cctVal = $(this).val();
      var cctNewVal = cctVal + '-';
      $(this).val(cctNewVal);
      break;
    case 9:
      var cctVal = $(this).val();
      var cctNewVal = cctVal + '-';
      $(this).val(cctNewVal);
      break;
    case 14:
      var cctVal = $(this).val();
      var cctNewVal = cctVal + '-';
      $(this).val(cctNewVal);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="creditCardText" maxlength="19" />
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/BrajinderSingh/kqg5ndxv/)

Comment: Nice try, but the result is a bit buggy if you delete or change numbers, even so, nice tryout

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved with vanilla JS and do not require plugin to do that. Refer to the code below. You can change the `var split` to suit your needs. Credits to https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/auto-formatting-input-value--cms-26745.

```js
(function($, undefined) {

    "use strict";

    // When ready.
    $(function() {
        
        var $form = $( "#form" );
        var $input = $form.find( "input" );

        $input.on( "keyup", function( event ) {
            
            console.log('sss')
            // When user select text in the document, also abort.
            var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
            if ( selection !== '' ) {
                return;
            }
            
            // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
            if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39] ) !== -1 ) {
                return;
            }
            
            var $this = $(this);
            var input = $this.val();
                    input = input.replace(/[\W\s\._\-]+/g, '');
                
                var split = 4;
                var chunk = [];
               
                for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i += split) {                              chunk.push( input.substr( i, split ) );
                }

                 console.log(chunk)
                $this.val(function() {
                    return chunk.join("-");
                });
        
        } );
        
        /**
         * ==================================
         * When Form Submitted
         * ==================================
         */
        $form.on( "submit", function( event ) {
            
            var $this = $( this );
            var arr = $this.serializeArray();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    arr[i].value = arr[i].value.replace(/[($)\s\._\-]+/g, ''); // Sanitize the values.
            };
            
            console.log( arr );
            
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="">

        <label for="number">Enter number</label>
        <div class="flex">
            <input id="number" name="number" type="text" maxlength="15" />
        </div>

</form>
```