# How to make dash("-") using keyup event in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an account number like this "12-1234-12-12-12345-123" using keyup event in jquery

I tried this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37617455/7734785) . it works for every two characters. But my case is a little bit different. My case is not every 2 characters. I have to make a dash("-") like this **12-1234-12-12-12345-123**

I tried this below code

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAccount1').keyup(function () {
    console.log("key press working");
    var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens

    var accSplit = $(this).val().split("-");
    if (accSplit.length == 0) {
        if (foo.length > 0) {
            foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join("-");
        }
    }
    if (accSplit.length == 1) {
        if (foo.length > 0) {
            foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
        }
    }
    $(this).val(foo);
});
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/inputmask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best method, yet it does create the string you're looking for. Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {

  function splitVal(v, a) {
    var str = [];
    if (a == undefined) {
      a = [2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3];
    }
    var val = "" + v.split("-").join("");
    var vl = val.length;
    var i = a[0], j = i + a[1], k = j + a[2], l = k + a[3], m = l + a[4], n = m + a[5];
    console.log(val, vl);
    switch (true) {
      case vl <= i:
        str[0] = val;
        break;
      case vl <= j:
        str.push(val.slice(0, i));
        str.push(val.slice(i));
        break;
      case vl <= k:
        str.push(val.slice(0, i));
        str.push(val.slice(i, j));
        str.push(val.slice(j));
        break;
      case vl <= l:
        str.push(val.slice(0, i));
        str.push(val.slice(i, j));
        str.push(val.slice(j, k));
        str.push(val.slice(k));
        break;
      case vl <= m:
        str.push(val.slice(0, i));
        str.push(val.slice(i, j));
        str.push(val.slice(j, k));
        str.push(val.slice(k, l));
        str.push(val.slice(l));
        break;
      case vl <= n:
        str.push(val.slice(0, i));
        str.push(val.slice(i, j));
        str.push(val.slice(j, k));
        str.push(val.slice(k, l));
        str.push(val.slice(l, m));
        str.push(val.slice(m));
        break;
      case vl > m:
        str.push(val.slice(0, i));
        str.push(val.slice(i, j));
        str.push(val.slice(j, k));
        str.push(val.slice(k, l));
        str.push(val.slice(l, m));
        str.push(val.slice(m, n));
        break;
    }
    console.log(str)
    return str.join("-");
  }
  $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAccount1').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val(splitVal($(this).val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAccount1" style="width: 200px;">
```

Using `switch()` we can conditionally create an array based on different lengths of the string. We break it into different parts of an array. Once the array is populated, we can use `.join()` to insert the "-" String where needed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: your code is working, can you help me with backspace,if user want to change, it is not working good. you try one time with back space

Comment: @Twusty it shouldn't perform when user press backspace

Comment: only the last dash"-" is not working when I press back space

Comment: @Liamneesan you're welcome. I updated the code a bit to allow for adjustable formats.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version, with predefined position mapping in an Array and then adding '-' according to this array position,

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAccount1').keyup(function () {
console.log("key press working");
var foo = $(this).val(); // Get Current Text Box Value
var hyphenPos=[3,8,11,14,20]//12-1234-12-12-12345-123 mapping hyphen positions
if($.inArray(foo.length,hyphenPos)>-1) // Check if we need to add hyphen
{
  var beforeHyphen=foo.substr(0,foo.length-1); // substring except last character
  var lastcharacter=foo.substr(foo.length-1,1); // last character
  var finalString=beforeHyphen+'-'+lastcharacter; // final result
  $(this).val(finalString); // show 
}
```

});