# How to write within the placeholder text?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a `text box` which has the place holder within as `__-__-__`  ("_" denotes a number) When I type in the box, it is entered as `123456`.
I need it to be entered as `12-34-56` (without manually adding the "-" character)

```
<input type="text" placeholder ="__-__-__" id="number"/>
```

Comment: you can also use 3 different input fields for that

Comment: each separated by `-`

Comment: @Sushrut you can use simple vanilla JS to achieve this. Refer to my answer which is the last on the thread for more info . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632525/insert-dash-after-every-4th-character-in-input/55339195#55339195. And dont forget to upvote my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cleave.js to format inputs

https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/