# Regular expression to insert dash into numbers after 3 and 4 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to insert dash into numbers but it is so hard to me...
What I want to do is that insert dash into after 3 and 4 digits, for example,

replacing `123123412345` to `123-1234-12345`.

The additional condition is that I replace it in `input` element. So I replace the number for every input event, i.e., I need to replace like

`1` to `1`
`12` to `12`
`123` to `123`
`1231` to `123-1`
...
`1231234` to `123-1234`
`12312341` to `123-1234-1`
...
`123123412345` to `123-1234-12345`

How can I do this using regex ??

Comment: I believe this can be achieved with format on the length of the input on change.
You may refer to this page [Insert dash after every 4th character in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632525/insert-dash-after-every-4th-character-in-input) @wallah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this regex:

- Regex

```
(?<=^\d{3}|^\d{7})(?=\d)
```

- Substitution

```
-
```

Check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/24LCtt/1/)

```js
const list = [
  1,
  12,
  123,
  1231,
  1231234,
  12312341,
  123123412345
];

const regex = /(?<=^\d{3}|^\d{7})(?=\d)/g;
const result = list.map(e => regex[Symbol.replace](e, '-'));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This doesn't feel efficient.  You are checking two lookbehinds and one lookahead on every character while looking for qualifying positions to add the `-`.  Right?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it needs to split the first 3 next 4 digits only, it can be done with following regexp replacement

```
str.replace(/((?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\b)|(?<=^\d{3})\d{4}(?!\b))/g, '$1-')
```

Input string has to be all digits

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
e.target.value = e.target.value.split('-').join('').replace(/((?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\b)|(?<=^\d{3})\d{4}(?!\b))/g, '$1-');
});

['1', '12', '123', '1231', '12312', '123123', '1231234', '12312341', '123123412', '1231234123', '12312341234', '123123412345']
.forEach(t => console.log(t.replace(/((?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\b)|(?<=^\d{3})\d{4}(?!\b))/g, '$1-')));
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" size="20">
```

Comment: Why are you `split().join()` like that?  Why not just replace `'-'` with `''` instead of generating an array and imploding it?

Comment: Does javascript have `\B` instead of `(?!\b)`?

Comment: `^\d{3}\B|(?<=^\d{3})\d{4}\B` with `$&-` seems cleaner (and more efficient) to me

Comment: thanks. you suggested a better option.