# Formatting a string to a certain format

Tags: javascript

I'm looking a way to reformat a phone number for display in Javascript. Here's an example of some of the data:

00-22 345 991

555922134

12450-123948

I want to reformat the number to the following 3 length format like: `555-922-134`

Assuming that dashes and spaces can be ignored and the last two blocks can be a length of 2 like: `002-234-59-91` or `124-501-349-48`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex with lookahead.

The [Positive Lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) looks for the pattern after the equal sign, but does not include it in the match.

> **x(?=y)**
>
> Matches 'x' only if 'x' is followed by 'y'. This is called a lookahead.
>
> For example, `/Jack(?=Sprat)/` matches 'Jack' only if it is followed by 'Sprat'. `/Jack(?=Sprat|Frost)/` matches 'Jack' only if it is followed by 'Sprat' or 'Frost'. However, neither 'Sprat' nor 'Frost' is part of the match results.

```js
function format(s) {
    return s.toString().replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\d{2,3}(?=..)/g, '$&-');
}

console.log(format('00-22 345 991'));
console.log(format('555922134'));
console.log(format('12450-123948'));
console.log(format(123456789));
console.log(format(12345678901));
console.log(format(1234567));
```

Answer (score 0):

Good evening! :)

This have been answered in a previous thread. :)

[Insert hyphens in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981487/insert-hyphens-in-javascript)

Hope this helps out - have a good night :)