# How to add "-" to specific digits in a number?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I want to automatically correct the proper format of IDs found on a website:

So im detecting if a specific digit-number is present in a website with

```
if (window.location.href.match(/\d{10}/)) {  alert('ID detected');} else {  alert('does not contain an ID');}
```

e.g **raw ID: "1234567899"**

now i want to add a minus "-" to it for it to show like likes "**123-456-7899**"

The minus has to be put in 1x after the first 3 digits and 1 x after the firs 6 digits

I am struggling to find a proper code for this, does anybody might have an idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Something like `s[:3] + '-' + s[3:6] + '-' + s[6:]` ? (in Python syntax)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert hyphens in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981487/insert-hyphens-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you! I have found this in javascript: `s.slice(0, 3) + "-" + s.slice(3, 6) + "-" + s.slice(6);`  but it does not work, maybe because its not fetching and saving the ID to slice?

Comment: This ID is in the location pathname or the query string?  And you want to format the number for display or use in your code?  The question isn't very clear.

Comment: Please apologize. The ID is not supposed to be in the pathname, its supposed to be found in a webpage (text)

Answer (score 0):

since its a string you can concatenate substrings with `-` to form your desired output

```js
const id = "1234567899";
const idDashed = `${id.substring(0,3)}-${id.substring(3,6)}-${id.substring(6,id.length)}`;
console.log(idDashed)
//"123-456-7899"
```

Comment: seems to work for the described problem don't know why this response was downvoted

Comment: [Please don't answer duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Add it to the duplicate if you want to. (Though it is already very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6981548/479156).)

Comment: @adiian Votes are to rate the quality of an answer. Answers that work can still be of poor quality or not useful.

Comment: makes sense, I flagged the question as duplicate, seemed unfair to downvote the only valid answer without an explanation

Comment: @adiian In the past it happened too often that people who explained downvotes got revenge-downvoted or even off-site harassed due to people not agreeing with them. As a result it is now advised **not** to explain downvotes anymore. (You can however still leave a comment explaining what is wrong with a post. Just don't refence the downvote.)

Comment: Thank you very much Adiian! I see that this would require a defined "const" `const id = "1234567899";` however i am trying to scan the website for the numbers so often the amount of IDs detected would be unpredictable if you take a look at my code above..

Comment: i found this "replace(/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)/, '$1$2$3-$4$5$6-$7$8$9$10')" but its not applying